# Invalid read size with function pointers in valgrind

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, valgrind

I have been having an issue with a fairly complex application, where valgrind reports invalid read size issues related to using function pointers. I have tried to reduce the problem to the smallest code possible. Very basically, there is a class `A` that defines a function `model` that takes some data as an argument. Class `B` has function pointer which is later set to be the `model` function of a class `A` instance. The function `B->run()` then calls the function pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    ~A(){};

    void model(std::vector<double>*);
};

void A::model(std::vector<double>* data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= (*data).size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << (*data)[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return;
}

class B
{
public:
    B() {};
    ~B(){};

    void run();
    std::function<void(std::vector<double>*)> f_model;  
};

void B::run()
{
    std::vector<double> data(10, 1);
    f_model(&data);

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();

    b->f_model = std::bind(&A::model, a, _1);
    b->run();

    delete b;
    delete a;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Running this under valgrind I get the message

```
==21841== Invalid read of size 8
==21841==    at 0x400C9B: A::model(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x40233D: void std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)>::operator()<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, void>(A*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*&&) const (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x4021F0: void std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)> (A*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>::__call<void, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*&&, 0ul, 1ul>(std::tuple<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*&&>&&, std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x401EB0: void std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)> (A*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>::operator()<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, void>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*&&) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x401B3C: std::_Function_handler<void (std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*), std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (A::*)(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)> (A*, std::_Placeholder<1>)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x401152: std::function<void (std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*)>::operator()(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) const (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x400D3C: B::run() (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x400E18: main (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==  Address 0x5a1c1a0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80 alloc'd
==21841==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21841==    by 0x401FBF: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x401D8E: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x40199E: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x401306: std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<double> const&) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x40107D: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::vector(unsigned long, double const&, std::allocator<double> const&) (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x400D1D: B::run() (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841==    by 0x400E18: main (in /home/code/snippets/cpptest/main)
==21841== 
0
==21841== 
==21841== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21841==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21841==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 137 bytes allocated
==21841== 
==21841== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

I am having a hard time why this invalid read size occurs but would like to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with function pointers. The error is here:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i <= (*data).size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << (*data)[i] << std::endl;
}
```

You are reading `(*data).size()+1` elements, i.e. 0 through `(*data).size()`, inclusive. In your case, that's 11 elements in a ten-element `std::vector`.

Replacing `<=` with `<` or `!=` will fix the invalid read:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != (*data).size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << (*data)[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You are a savior. Unbelievable, I just spent two days trying to debug this. This was the first time using function pointers so I was certain I had to be doing something illegal there. This has happened so often to me, where I use something completely new for the first time and always assume that if something goes wrong it has to do with the new thing and I overlook absolute trivial mistakes.

Comment: @Pankrates: `<=` in a `for` loop condition always merits a close look.